# gcloud beta ml init-project -- Error: Project does not exist, or you do not have permission

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to get started with Google Machine Learning using these instructions: [Getting Setup](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up)

When I run `gcloud beta ml init-project` I get

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.init-project) Project [mnist1-151907] does not exist, 
>   or you do not have permission to access it.

I'm running this command on Google Cloud's Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine created under my projectID mnist1-151907 and I've given this machine access to all of Google Cloud's APIs.
The log ~/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.12.23/13.14.03.742050.log says

> ... "error": { "code": 403,
>   "message": Google Cloud Resource Manager API has not been used in project mnist1-151907 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=mnist1-151907  ...

I followed the log's instructions and the API is enabled, but I'm still getting the same error.  Has anyone experienced this error or can offer a suggestion?  Thank you.

Comment: Update:  everything works fine on an amazon aws server.  I installed the software on the amazon server according to original post.  I even successfully submitted a ML training job too Google's ML farm via the cloudML api.  Then I took the generated .config directory on the amazon server to the google cloud vm where the command originally failed and was able to submit a ML job.  I did not run the "gcloud beta ml init-project" again for fear that this will muck w/ the .config directory. Go figure, that amazon's vm installs w/ correct permissions and google's vm did not.

Comment: I'd still rather make the command "gcloud beta ml init-project" work directly from google's vm w/o resorting to an amazon vm for help.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error after enabling the API.  I had to play a little re-authenticating with the project the gcloud tool. i.e. [gcloud init](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init), [gcloud auth revoke](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke) and [gcloud auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)